# Replacing iphone interface with terminal

Tags: iphone, terminal, jailbreak, ui, cydia

Is there an app in cydia or just anyway to replace the normal interface(having to tap icons in order to open) with a terminal. Im using mobileterminal but its just an app. Im looking to replace it all with a log screen.

Comment: what is a log screen?

Comment: oh well for this you should have some advanced programming and OS Knowlegde, you can boot your iPhone in an CommandLine with an Jailbreak - and you may can change some Settings to load a Terminal instead of SpringBoard (may - my last Jailbreak was in iOS4 i think)

Comment: This is possible, but there's no easy way of doing it right now. You'd have to set it all up yourself.